# StringBuilder remove lines

Tags: sql, vb.net, stringbuilder

I have a insert SQL statement enclosed in a stringbuilder. I want to remove the two lines for col2 if the col2 variable contains a NULL value. This would allow me to insert a NULL value into col2

This is my code.

```
Private Sub insertStmt(ByVal col2 As Integer)
    If IsDBNull(col2) Then
        'Remove line 'Col2' 
    End If

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

    sb.Append("INSERT INTO TABLE")
    sb.Append("(")
    sb.Append("Col1,")
    sb.Append("Col2,")
    sb.Append("Col3,")
    sb.Append("Col4")
    sb.Append(")")
    sb.Append("VALUES")
    sb.Append("(")
    sb.Append("1,")
    sb.Append(" " & col2 & ", ")
    sb.Append("'abc',")
    sb.Append("'xyz'")
    sb.Append(")")
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a bad way to create SQL as it doesnt protect against SQL Injection attacks and various other things.  Use SQL Paramters

Answer (score 2):

First, I agree emphatically with the suggestion not to build SQL this way.
Also, `col2` is an `int`. It will never be null.
But to answer your question, if you were going to do this, it would be easier to just not add them in the first place.

Assuming that `col2` was something that *could* be null, replace those two lines with

```
If Not IsDBNull(col2) Then sb.Append("Col2,")

If Not IsDBNull(col2) Then sb.Append(" " & col2 & ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you do this before you create stringbuilder

forexample :

```
 Dim values As New Dictionary(Of String, object)
    values.Add("col1", variable1)
    values.Add("col2", variable2)
    values.Add("col3", variable3)
    Dim main_sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim cols_sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim vals_sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each row As KeyValuePair(Of String, object) In values
        If IsDBNull(row.Value) = False Then
            cols_sb.Append("[" & row.Key & "],")
            vals_sb.Append("'" & row.Value & "',")
        End If
    Next
    main_sb.Append("INSERT INTO TABLE (" & cols_sb.ToString.Substring(0, cols_sb.ToString.Length - 1) & ") values (" & vals_sb.ToString.Substring(0, vals_sb.ToString.Length - 1) & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
sb.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO TABLE(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES(1,{0},'abc','xyz')", col2);
```

neat eh?

Comment: @snoopcommands -- sounds like you made a typo, what does sb.ToString() display?

Comment: sb.tostring = "INSERT INTO TABLE(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES(1,,'abc','xyz')"

sql accpets  "INSERT INTO TABLE(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES(1,null,'abc','xyz')"

Comment: @snoopcommands -- that is not possible with the code you shown -- col2 is an integer and it would never be formatted as the empty string.  Is col2 actually a string?